# triggering one pipeline from another with particular branch

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have ABC & DEF pipelines and I want DEF to run post ABC successful run so I have written YAML like below in DEF.

```
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: test   # Internal name of the source pipeline
      source: ABC
      trigger: true
```

Pipeline triggering but I want to trigger pipeline for branches under release/* latest branch. The pipeline triggering for master in DEF. ABC is just cron JOB. is there any way to trigger DEF for branch we want instead of master.

Comment: Was this every figured out ? The solution below does not work and it only triggers the default branch build.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the following yaml to have a try:

```
trigger:

- DEF



resources:

 pipelines:

   - pipeline: test

     project: your_project_name

     source: ABC

     branch: release/* #latest branch

     trigger:

      branches:

        - release/* #latest branch
```